# Deciding on platform for typing tutor application

Tags: c#, html, cross-platform

For a customer I need to write an application which will allow students (9-10 year old children) to log in online with credentials, and make typing exercises. Basically, they receive a text on screen and must type it over in a separate box.

The app must be able to log their speed (words and characters per minute), and calculate their error percentage. They may not copy/paste the source text, the source text words should be highlighted according to the current word they are typing, etc.

Logins and exercise texts are stored in a database, and statistics and results must be logged back in the database (MSSQL server as it will be a Windows hosting platform). The database administration module will be designed in ASP.NET MVC.

It must support as much clients as possible (Windows, Mac, Android, ...).

I'm unsure in which technology I should design it. My knowledge is in the .NET world (C#, mostly WinForms and ASP.NET MVC to some extent).

Is this something that can be done in MVC (HTML5, jquery, ..). I'm about to purchase the Telerik controls suite so if this can help in that, please suggest it.

Or is this something you would suggest developing in a Java applet ? Or Silverlight (but fearing here for browser compatibility) ?

I know this is not a real specific coding question but unsure where to get help for this.

Thanks to anyone wanting to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot solution, although you mentioned technology, it can be achieved all of them, it depend exact what technology you know. You have two things to decide first is front end where as it is only so better user Html5/css/Javascript and with framework like jquery or sancha, you might need to use node.js or something for modular javascript.

For backend it all depend on you, if you know .net you can make it in it, otherwise you might use open source php/mysql (lamp stack). But I smelling from your post a simple but it is not simple at front end it require a lot work to achieve it.

Check this link https://github.com/voithos/swiftcode might help you, Good luck.